# how to read a value from filename and insert/replace it in the file?

Tags: shell, cat, tee

I have to run many python script which differ just with one parameter. I name them as runv1.py, runv2.py, runv20.py. I have the original script, say runv1.py. Then I make all copies that I need by

```
cat runv1.py | tee runv{2..20..1}.py
```

So I have runv1.py,.., runv20.py. But still the parameter v=1 in all of them.

Q: how can I also replace v parameter to read it from the file name? so e.g in runv4.py then v=4. I would like to know if there is any one-line shell command or combination of commands. Thank you!

PS: direct editing each file is not a proper solution when there are too many files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below for loop will serve your purpose I think

```
for i in `ls | grep "runv[0-9][0-9]*.py"`
do
l=`echo $i | tr -d [a-z.]`
sed -i 's/v/'"$l"'/g' runv$l.py
done
```

Below command was to pass the parameter to script extracted from the filename itself

```
ls | grep "runv[0-9][0-9]*.py" | tr -d [a-z.] | awk '{print "./runv"$0".py "$0}' | xargs sh
```

in the end instead of sh you can use python or bash or ksh.

Comment: Thank you, it almost works. could you tell me what is in grep [0-9]? is it a range or just all number combination? I have tried several times and is not very clear to me what is its meaning. e.g what is I want to do the job (replace) not on all script but on an interval e.g on runv1.py ==> runv8.py?

Comment: my apologies for inconvenience. [0-9] is for single number pattern between string "runv" and ".py" .Now I have modified my answer to use [0-9][0-9]* meaning at least one digit should be there and second digit ([0-9]*) may or may not be there. please run again.

Comment: Thank you! it works perfectly, I just edited one small point. in the sed command to be more clear, v=1 to be replaced with v=$l